# In Java PriorityQueue, why does children of queue[n] are queue[2*n+1] and queue[2*(n+1)]?

Tags: java, priority-queue

Min-Heap implementation in Java is represented by PriorityQueue which, in turn, is backed by `transient Object[] queue;`

The quote from its javadoc is

> Priority queue represented as a balanced binary heap: the two children
> of queue[n] are queue[2n+1] and queue[2(n+1)].

Why not queue[2n] and queue[2n+1] as Tim Roughgarden states here https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-graphs-data-structures/lecture/KKqlm/heaps-implementation-details-advanced-optional 08:00?

Comment: What will happen if we ask a child of the 0'th element?

Comment: @caco3 I'll answer 1 and 2. https://www.coursera.org/learn/algorithms-graphs-data-structures/lecture/KKqlm/heaps-implementation-details-advanced-optional 08:00

Comment: It is for the `PriorityQueue` in java :) but if we would use `2n` and `2n+1` we would get `0` and `1` which is not correct. Using `2n` and `2n + 1` works for languages where indexes start at 1, but in Java they start at 0, that's the reason

Comment: @Pasha indexing in the video starts at 1, that's why the formulas are valid there but in java must be adjusted

Comment: Thank you @caco3, you can issue your comment as a standalone response

Answer (score 1):

As caco3 mentions in the commments, if the elements in a priority queue are stored in an array, the designers of that priority queue data structure can decide to store the first item in the array at position 0 or position 1.

Putting the first item in position 0 means that children are in positions 2N + 1 and 2N + 2.  When the first item is stored in position 1 the children are in positions 2N and 2N + 1.

Either choice can lead to a correct implementation.  Starting at 0 saves a little space.  But some people feel that the math and code is more elegant when starting at 1.